# What is a good word covering "studying the bad effects of something"

Tags: word-request

I am lookin for a word covering the meaning "studying the bad effects of something".

Can *pathology* be a good choice?

in my case that *something* refers to *Tourism Development in a natural ecosystem*.

Comment: You need to be more specific what "something" is. I expect the answer might depend on that. Some example sentence would be helpful too.

Comment: From the full OED, definition II 3 d: ***In extended use:** the study or investigation of abnormality or malfunction in the moral, social, linguistic, **or other sphere;** a moral, social, etc., **abnormality or malfunction**.* So yes, it's probably a good choice.

Comment: @user3169 Tourism Development in a natural ecosystem

Comment: I'm fond of the word 'deleterious'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term is an 'impact assessment' or an 'impact study', and one can narrow it down even further, depending on what's being assessed.

In the case of Tourism Development in a natural ecosystem, a reasonable label would be **[Environmental Impact Assessment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_impact_assessment)** or **Environmental Impact Study.**

These studies are generally carried out to assess whether tourism in a region is [sustainable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_tourism), i.e.  makes only a positive impact on the environment, society and economy.

Answer (score 1):

Medically, the word you may be looking for is

> [**Epidemiology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemiology) - the study and analysis of the patterns, causes, and effects of health and disease conditions in defined populations. It is the cornerstone of public health, and shapes policy decisions and evidence-based practice by identifying risk factors for disease and targets for preventive healthcare.

In your environmental example

> [**impact evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_evaluation) - assesses the changes that can be attributed to a particular intervention, such as a project, program or policy, both the intended ones, as well as ideally the unintended ones

may be more appropriate.